# Batch file to replace part of file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm looking for a batch file that can just replace part of the file names on a group of files.  They're all in one directory and named XYZ123_DETAILXXX_R.slddrw.  I want to replace the _DETAIL part with "-" and the _R part with "-CM".  Obviously no quotes.  One complication though could be that I only want to make this change on the .slddrw file, not the .sldprt files also in that directory.  I found other scripts to remove parts of file names, but not selective replacement.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the _DETAILXXX, What can XXX be? numbers, letters, signs, all, ...?

Comment: the XX can be numbers and letters.  I wouldn't expect to see any special characters there though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Old=_DETAIL"
Set "New=-"
Set "Old_=_R"
Set "New_=-CM"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.slddrw') do (
    set File=%%~nxa
    set File=!File:%Old_%=%New_%!
    set File=!File:%Old%=%New%!
    ren "%%a" "!File!"
)
Pause&Exit
```

Comment: The first half, the _DETAIL line works great. but the _R part breaks.  It says "the system cannot find the file specified."  Could it be looking for the original name on that line?

Comment: My apologies, place this in the directory and you are good to go.

Comment: No problem, please mark it as answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the echo when performing real renaming:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.slddrw') do (
    set filename=%%~nxa
    set filename=!filename:_R=-CM!
    set filename=!filename:_DETAIL=-!
    echo ren "%%a" "!filename!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
 setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

 for %%a in ("c:\somewhere\*_DETAIL*_R.slddrw"
 ) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
    set "newName=%%c" & set "newName=%%b-!newName:~6!-CM%%~xa"
    if not exist "%%~dpa!newName!" echo ren "%%~fa" "!newName!"
 )
```

Just one more. If the output to console is correct, remove the `echo` command.